# How to disable monitoring index spawning in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, configuration, monitoring

I've been playing around with Elasticsearch recently for my company and have noticed that now, Elasticsearch keeps spawning new indices automatically for monitoring. I don't want this to happen and am looking for a way to stop it. I don't remember ever changing monitoring settings so I do not know where to even start. Google doesn't have any related answers and neither does StackOverFlow. Elastic documentation just says to edit elasticsearch.yml file but there isn't any monitoring settings in there... Kind of at a dead end here.
[image: Indices being spawned by both Kibana and "monitoring"]

Answer (score 1):

The monitoring indices are configured through the setting `xpack.monitoring.history.duration`, the defaul value is `7d`, which means that the monitoring history will be kept for 7 days, so you will have around 7 indices.

If you do not want those indices you will need to disable monitoring setting `xpack.monitoring.enabled` to `false` in the `elasticsearch.yml` file.

You can also change the duration history, but the minimum value is `1d`, to do that just add the setting in the `elasticsearch.yml` file with the desired duration.

You can find more information in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/monitoring-settings.html).

Comment: The setting was not in the elasticsearch.yml file so I added it. Edit: Adding the setting did not help, monitoring indexes still spawning.

Comment: Not all possible settings are present in the `elasticsearch.yml` file, some will use default values if not present. Which config did you put in the file? Do you have other nodes? Put the same config in all of them and restarted the service?

Comment: In elasticsearch-6.6.1 > config > elasticsearch.yml I added the line: xpack.monitoring.enabled: false, but I don't think this changed anything because monitoring indices are still spawning.